# Show that length of sine is equal to length of cosine on the same interval.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, periodic-functions, arc-length

Let $$f(x)=\sin(x)\\\ g(x)=\cos(x)$$
Let $L_1$ be $$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\space dx$$
And $L_2$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\space dx$$
I.e. L is a length of sine/cosine during it's period interval.

Numerical approach shows that these two integrals are equal. It seems reasonable, as both have the same wavelength and frequency.

*How can one show above relationship holds? ($L_1=L_2$)*

Comment: $$x\mapsto \frac{\pi}{2}-x$$

Comment: Informally, their graphs are made up of the same "parts" on that interval: One complete "hump" above the $x$ axis, and one complete "hump" below the $x$ axis.

Comment: It is an Elliptic integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, we want to exploit the fact that $\sin$ and $\cos$ "look the same". The theorem that lets us do this is integration by substitution. Let's define, for convenience, the functions $\ell_1(x) = \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}$, and $\ell_2(x) = \sqrt{1 + \sin^2 x}$, so
\begin{align*}
 L_1 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \ell_1(x) \,\mathrm dx \\
 L_2 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \ell_2(x) \,\mathrm dx
\end{align*}
Now note that
\begin{align*}
 L_1 = \int_0^{\pi/2} \ell_1(x) \,\mathrm dx
  + \int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi} \ell_1 (x) \,\mathrm dx \\
 L_2 = \int_0^{\pi/2} \ell_2(x) \,\mathrm dx
  + \int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi} \ell_2 (x) \,\mathrm dx
\end{align*}
However, using the substitution $u = \pi/2 - x$, as given in the comments,
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\pi/2} \ell_1(x) \,\mathrm dx
  &= \int_{\pi/2}^0 (-\ell_2(u)) \,\mathrm du \\
  &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \ell_2(u) \,\mathrm du
\end{align*}
And from the substitution $u = \tfrac 52 \pi - x$,
\begin{align*}
 \int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi} \ell_1 (x) \,\mathrm dx
  &= \int_{2\pi}^{\pi/2} (-\ell_2 (u)) \,\mathrm du \\
  &= \int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi} \ell_2 (u) \,\mathrm du
\end{align*}
It is an exercise in trigonometric identities to establish that
$\ell_1(\pi/2 - u) = \ell_2(u)$, and $\ell_2(\tfrac 52 \pi - u) = \ell_2(u)$.

From these equalities, it follows that $L_1 = L_2$.

In fact, you can use this approach to show that for any function $f$,
\begin{equation*}
 \int_0^{2\pi} f(\sin x) \,\mathrm dx =
 \int_0^{2\pi} f(\cos x) \,\mathrm dx
\end{equation*}
This also holds on smaller intervals like $[0, \tfrac 12 \pi]$ or $[0, \pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Use property of definite integration: $\int_0^{2a}f(x)dx=2\int_0^a f(x)dx\ \  \forall\ \ f(2a-x)=f(x)$
$$L_1=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx=2\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx$$
$$L_2=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\ dx=2\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\ dx=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}\ dx$$
Use property of definite integration: $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$
$$=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}\ dx=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx$$
$$\therefore L_1=L_2$$